# select from same table where two columns match and third doesn't

Tags: mysql

I have table fedcodes with columns `FEATURE_NAME`, `STATE_ALPHA`, `COUNTY_NAME` and population data -  amongst other data. 
I need to select all entries where `FEATURE_NAME` and `STATE_ALPHA` match, and `COUNTY_NAME` is different. I also need all data from such rows, not just those three listed. 
Further I need to have both/all/ of such occurrences shown in output list. Please help.

I have tried inner join but it won't work on same table. Also I have tried the following script:

*select fedcodes.*, count(*) num, `FEATURE_NAME`, `STATE_ALPHA` from fedcodes group by 
`FEATURE_NAME`, `STATE_ALPHA` having num > 1 ORDER BY `fedcodes`.`FEATURE_NAME`  DESC*

But I don't know how to add term that `COUNTY_NAME` is not the same and it outputs only one row with num column showing number of occurrences.

**Example:**

```
    ID  FEATURE_CLASS   FEATURE_ID  FEATURE_NAME    CENSUS_CODE     CENSUS_CLASS_CODE   GSA_CODE    OPM_CODE    STATE_NUMERIC   STATE_ALPHA     COUNTY_SEQUENCE     COUNTY_NUMERIC  COUNTY_NAME     DATE_CREATED    PRIMARY_LATITUDE    PRIMARY_LONGITUDE   DATE_EDITED     fips    COUNTRY_NAME    POPULATION_DATA     city_county_allocate    is_county
    146627  Populated Place     1616849     Wyandotte   88900   P1  5310    265310163   26  MI  1   163     Wayne   1980-04-14 00:00:00     42.2142064  -83.1499239     03/20/2008  26163   US  25883   100     1
    147139  Populated Place     1617956     Wyandotte   88890   U6  NULL    NULL    26  MI  1   61  Houghton    1980-04-14 00:00:00     46.8899335  -88.8754114     NULL    26061   US  0   0   0

    34  Populated Place     2195    Bumstead    8360    U6  NULL    NULL    4   AZ  1   13  Maricopa    1980-02-08 00:00:00     33.5733726  -112.3568269    NULL    04013   US  0   0   0
```

-As you can see from example Wyandote is in two counties hence two entries one with population data 25883 and another with population data 0 So I need both of those entries. And Bumstead is in one county only so I don't need that selected. I hope this example explain things a bit better.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: MY mistake. I focused on posting the problem so forgot to add what I have tried. I edited the post and added what I tried. Please understand that I'm not too familiar with MYSQL in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some psedo code to get you started. Basically you need to join the table back to itself using the rules you descibed above, then return whatever field you need.

```
SELECT  ... -- Add all the field you need from both intances of your table below
FROM    fedcodes T1 -- First instance of your table
INNER JOIN
        fedcodes T2 -- Second instance of your table
ON      T1.FEATURE_NAME = T2.FEATURE_NAME
AND     T1.STATE_ALPHA = T2.STATE_ALPHA 
AND     T1.COUNTY_NAME <> T2.COUNTY_NAME
```

Comment: When I add all the fields from the table in line1 it returns: Column 'FEATURE_CLASS' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: You need to specify which instance of the fedcodes table it is coming from. Try `T1.FEATURE_CLASS`, that lets it know which copy to select that field from.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''COUNTY_NUMERIC`, fedcodes.`COUNTY_NAME`, fedcodes.`DATE_CREATED`, fedcodes.`PRI' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT f1.* 
 FROM fedcodes f1 JOIN
      fedcodes f2 ON f1.feature_name = f2.feature_name
                 AND f1.state_alpha = f2.state_alpha 
                 AND f1.county_name <> f2.county_name
```

**[SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf76a/1)**

Comment: this one returns me the whole table. Even when there is one entry in column it will have a match in that same column in second instance of the table.

Comment: @user2364198 Did you take a look at sqlfiddle I've provided? Please provide sample data (a few relevant rows).

Comment: I have attached a few example rows and short explanation. Sorry I'm noob at using stackoverflow as well. :(

Comment: Actually this did what I needed. I must have made some stupid syntax error the first time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2364198 I've updated sqlfiddle with your data. It gives you exactly what you've asked.